# Citation Style Language matching BibLaTeX 'plain'

Tags: bibliographies, citing

Is there a [Citation Style Language](https://citationstyles.org/) which replicates the style provided by BibTeX when using `\bibliographystyle{plain}`?

(Note this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208296/latex-default-citation-and-bibliography-style-with-pandoc) which requires German language support.)

Comment: There is no such thing as a Citation Style Language (`.csl`) file that works with `biblatex`. The `plain` style is not a `biblatex`, but a BibTeX style. (I'm aware that these two points address different points/questions, but I'm not quite sure how to parse the 'with' in your first sentence: Do you want a CSL to use with `biblatex`?)

Comment: Please clarify how your question might be on topic for this site. There is no such thing as a "default" bib style in BibTeX; without a valid `\bibliographystyle` directive, BibTeX won't even produce a formatted bibliography. BibTeX's `plain` *citation* call-out style is numeric.

Comment: I should probably say that Citation Style Language is generally not on topic here. CSL styles can be requested in the Zotero forum. See https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/wiki/Requesting-Styles for more instructions.

Comment: Thanks all: @moewe, no, I am not looking for a CSL to use with biblatex; rather, I'm looking for a CSL that matches the citation style provided by biblatex/bibtex. Per on topic, this issue arises when using pandoc to create LaTeX documents.

Comment: The styles produced by `biblatex` and BibTeX are different (you can't use styles for one for the other) and there are plenty of them out there, so you have to be specific. You say `\bibliographystyle{plain}` which is a BibTeX style and not a `biblatex` style, so I'll retag the question.

Comment: Even if your question is about generating a LaTeX document, the components of `pandoc` that work with CSL are completely unrelated to the LaTeX components and there are not a lot of users here who know and use CSL. I think the general consensus here is that pandoc questions are definitely on-topic if they are about the LaTeX code produced by pandoc or real LaTeX components of pandoc. But in other cases other sites might be better In particular the Zotero forum takes CSL style requests.

Comment: Got it, thank you for your help; I will reach out over at the Zotero forums.